# Effect handlers, arrows and applicatives

Tags: lambda-calculus, type-systems, operational-semantics

After reading Lindley's paper on [effect handlers for arrows and applicatives](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2633628.2633636), I got the gist about dynamic and static flow and that it was added to the effect system and so on. However, I do not understand two things about this paper:

1. Why does it need that `G` unary operator? I kind of understand that you have to have another type to represent the function as an arrow, and that's how it was solved. I do not understand why is `G` needed for applicatives.
2. Why it requires a lambda expression receiving a `z` of type `B` for both arrow and applicative handling? Does it mean that everything that's static gets dumped into scope?

I've read previous papers by Lindley on effect handlers, and I am familiar with arrows and applicatives in Haskell.